# What fraction of the values of a quadratic polynomial can be prime?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, sieve-theory, effective-results

I have an explicit, monic quadratic polynomial $P(x)$ and an integer $m$. Can I bound the number of prime values in $P(0), P(1),  \ldots, P(m)$? A reference would be appreciated, if available. An effective result would be best, but I'll take what I can get. I would expect sieve theory to produce a bound of the right order of magnitude but again, I'll take what I can get!

I am aware of the large literature on maximizing Hardy-Littlewood products for quadratic polynomials but that's not what I'm looking for.

Bonus points if the method extends to larger degrees.

Comment: If $m$ is small with respect to the discriminant of the polynomial then the proportion can be equal to $100\%$. For example, the quadratic polynomial $P(x) = x^2 + x + 41$ is famously prime for $x = 1, \cdots, 40$. More generally, if the class number of the quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-4k+1})$ is equal to one, then the quadratic polynomial $x^2 + x + k$ will be prime for $x = 1, \cdots, k-1$. The largest example is $k = 41$ by the solution to Gauss's class number one problem. In any slightly larger regime, sieve theory answers the question.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao you may mean $x^2\color{blue}{-}x+41$ is prime through $x=40$. With the $+$ sign $x=40$ gives $41^2$.

Answer (score 1):

We can easily show that it is possible to achieve only primes for some given $m$ and $\mathcal{P(x)}, x=1,2,...m$ (e.g., $\mathcal{P(x)}:= x^2 - x + m$ and $m:=17$ or $m=41$, see OEIS sequences $A007635$, $A056561$).
On the other hand, we see that there are only a finite number of values of $m$ such that $\mathcal{P(x)}:= x^2 - x + m$ originates more than $\frac{m}{2}$ primes for $x=1,2,3,\dots,m$ (see [A356751](https://oeis.org/A356751)).
In general, you can analyze the prime density of $x^2 + x + m$, for $m$ odd and $x=1,2,...,m$, from the OEIS sequence [A188424](https://oeis.org/A188424).

Finally, you can see that the Hardy-Littlewood constant of the polynomial $x^2 - x + m$ is the same as $x^2 + x + m$ (as $m$ grows, the number of primes in the range differs by one, at most, and consequently the aforementioned discrepancy becomes irrelevant).
Record values of $m$ in the above are given by the sequence [A331940](https://oeis.org/A331940).

Comment: But can we show that at most m/3, or m/100, or m/log log m are prime, with finitely many exceptions?

Comment: No, we cannot (or at least, I am not aware that anybody as achieved that result). Furthermore, I cannot even speculate that there would be finitely many exceptions to $m/100$ or $m/(log (log(m)))$, since, from the last comment of $A331940$, we see that the value of C of $x^2+x+3399714628553118047$ is well above $10$ so that $A331940$ doesn't seem to be finite.

Comment: I agree that C is unbounded, so we expect that lim sup m/log m is infinite. But I’d be shocked if m/100 was achievable infinitely often. Not sure about m/log log m.

Comment: Absolutely, it would be unexpected but who knows? BTW, very interesting topic.